# Calculate the edge net direction between two nodes either

Tags: sql, sql-server, network-analysis

I require some assistance. I want to be able to calculate the net direction of edges within SQL. The data looks like the following:

```
Select *
from data

Source destination weight
A      B           12
C      B           5
D      A           7
B      A           6
F      G           20
B      C           2
G      F           7
```

I would like the end result to look like the following:

```
Source destination weight
A      B           6
C      B           3
D      A           7
F      G           13
```

Is there a simple way of writing this in SQL?

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have started with extensive research online to find similar problems, however nothing found. I don't have that much experience in SQL and would even just appreciate a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` and `group by` least, greatest as follows:

```
select IIF(source < destination, source, destination) as src, 
       IIF(source > destination, source, destination) as dest
       sum(case when source < destination then weight else -weight end) as weight
  from your_Table
group by IIF(source < destination, source, destination),  
         IIF(source > destination, source, destination)
```

Comment: @MalcolmdeBruyn . . . This can return negative values for the weights, which doesn't seem to be what you really want.  If you want a solution that does not produce negative values, ask a *new* question with a clear explanation and sample data.